# Shaders look bad when importing meshes into blender. How to go about fixing the issue?

Tags: mesh, shaders, import, remesh

[image]I am trying to import a model that I designed in Autodesk Fusion 360 into blender to do UVs before exporting to UE5. The meshes have basic beveled arches and the shading looks awful once I import them to blender. I have watched all kinds of tutorials on modifications to add to the meshes, remeshing, etc. and I can't figure out a solution that works for me. Let me know if anyone can lend me a hand in figuring this out, Thanks!

-Jake [image: photo 1]

[[image: photo 2][2]]

[image]

Comment: You mean the normals?  The normals look weird-- different-- probably, because Autodesk triangulates differently than Blender (which can affect tris, but *really* affects ngons.)  Can you export a triangulated mesh with custom normals?  Can you show us the Autodesk version?

Comment: @Nathan Thanks for getting back to me. I watched a bunch of tutorials trying to figure this out and some people had similar looking issues but said it was due to shaders so I probably got it confused. I am very new to blender so bare with me. This model was originally a CAD model that was exported to a mesh format and the thing that sucks about Fusion 360 is that there are no custom mesh settings on export. I recently got full trials to Rhino and 3Ds max because I am outgrowing fusion and getting more into Archviz rendering than basic cad design. I linked a screenshot of the model in Fusion

Comment: @Nathan Do you think a workflow would be better where I export from Fusion to Rhino or 3Ds max and then re-export to blender? or is there a way to just fix the normals in blender?

Comment: You can fix the normals in Blender, but to do so, you want a copy of the mesh with good normals in Blender-- if you had that, you wouldn't need to fix anything.  I wouldn't think much about multiple exports, that just multiplies the number of places where things can go wrong.  Instead, I would be looking at my options, in Fusion, to triangulate and write custom normals.  I would expect any decent 3D package to allow you to do this.  But as I have never used Fusion myself, I can't advise regarding that.   Are there any places for Fusion users where you can ask?

Comment: And the "shaders" thing is confusing, because it's the only info about what you think the problem is, but the terminology is weird.  Because you're not showing us a "shaded" view in Blender, you're showing us a matcap-- maybe elsewhere, this'd be called "sphere mapped".  But it doesn't look like you're showing us a shaded view in Fusion either, it looks specifically *un*shaded, with a wireframe.  Yet, the matcap view is ideal for seeing normals, and the Fusion view is totally useless for seeing normals.  So it's hard to figure out exactly what you mean by "shaders" here.